# Can't delete in c++

Tags: c++

I have a simple doubly linked list example that I'm working on, but for some reason I  keep getting the error: `pointer being freed was not allocated` when I try to delete

Here is a code snipet of the insert at end of list method

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insertAtEnd(T *o)
{
    node *newNode = new node;
    newNode->o = o;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = last;
    if(last != NULL)
        last->next = newNode;
    last = newNode;
    if(first == NULL)
        first = newNode;
    delete(newNode);            // This delete call will usually be in another method
}                               // It is just here right now for testing
```

This class has two instance fields, a pointer to the beginning of the list and a pointer to the end, first and last respecitvely.  Each node is a struct as follows:

```
struct node {
    node   *next;
    node   *prev;
    T      *o;
};
```

So far I have only tested with inserting 1 node, but I always get the same error.  However, if I comment out the lines

```
if(first == NULL)
    first = newNode;
```

it works.  Help please? Thanks

EDIT: Both first and last start as `NULL`.

Comment: Does the code you posted here fail? Or are you talking about some other code that we don't get to see?

Comment: Its a global variable that I'm setting equal to null in the constructor.  Same goes for last

Comment: This is a code snipet, but I have a simple test program:       List<int> list; int *ip = new int(3); list.insertBack(ip);  And it fails when I run it.

Comment: @Nosrettap: Almost surely it's a **different** `delete` that's causing the problem then. Add a `first = NULL;` if you're deleting the first-node.

Comment: @Nosrettap: You're doing something wrong if you're resorting to global variables in a linked-list implementation. Did you mean 'member variables' when you said 'global variables'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is this delete that is causing the problem because in my test program I am only calling this method

Comment: @Nosrettap: You should be storing T by value in your nodes. If, for some reason, you want to store pointers in your list, you instantiate your template like this: `List<int*>`.

Comment: You create new node, insert for it into list and then... delete this new node without updating the list. Any particular reason for doing that?

Comment: @SegTerm: Read the comment beside the delete statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, unfortunately, not provided the entirety of your code. You've omitted the section containing your error, so I must speculate as to the exact cause.

The error you are seeing indicates that `delete` is being called on an address that was not produced via `new`. This probably means you are inadvertently doing a *value assignment*, instead of a *pointer assignment*, and then attempting to free the copied (stack-allocated) variable. One specific way this could happen is if you attempt to `delete mynode->o`, since `o` could be the address of a stack variable.

Double-check that every type which should be a `node*` is a `node*`, not a `node` or a `node**`. Compiling your code with `-Wall -Wextra` may produce helpful additional warnings and should be a first debugging step if not a general practice.

If your types and assignments are all correct, you may be using a C++ library or compiler that doesn't give you particular double-free messages; this would expand the scope of the error you see to include freeing the same memory twice. Try printing an address just before you free it (or using a debugger to the same effect). When you see the same address come up twice, that's it.

This may be obvious, but you can't have the `delete` call there and have your function work right. `first` and `last` will point to freed memory. Felt that needed to be said, just in case.

Comment: I think you may have solved it.  When you say that I can't have a pointer point to freed memory, does that mean that I can't have it pointing there even for a second? Even if I don't use that pointer?  If so, should I just set the pointer first to NULL before deleting?  Sorry, I'm new to C++

Comment: @Nosrettap No, it can point to freed memory as long as you don't use it - but it's a recipe for disaster to leave it that way. With the `delete` call where you have it, `first` and `last` will both point to freed memory after one call.

Comment: Because the method above works if I set first equal to NULL right before I delete

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using `safe_ptr<T>` for `first` and/or `last`? Then you need a cast to `T*` when comparing to NULL or 0. But I still cannot see an error being caused.

It is more likely that the list destructor does a second delete on the node.